# Building multiple releases with l3build from same source

Tags: l3build

I am trying to build multiple variantsof my module from the same source directories using `l3build`.

I intend to provide multiple `build.lua` configurations, one for each variant.

## Preliminary Question:

As far as I am concerned, I can not specify to `l3build`, which `build.lua` it should use, right?
If this was somehow possible, I would just create files `build-varA.lua`, `build-varB.lua` and call `l3build` with each configuration.
If it is possible, I'd like to know how, and then the remainder of my question becomes obsolete.

*Currently not possible according to comment by Joseph Wright, author of l3build.*

## Main Question

Since I am not counting on a positive answer to my preliminary question, I have setup the following structure:

```
<project root>
 |-varA
 |  |-build.lua
 |-varB
 |  |-build.lua
 |-tex
 |  |-images
 |  |  |-exampleimage.png
 |  |-latex
 |  |  |-mytemplates
 |  |  |  |-mypackage.sty
```

The content is not important at this point (If reproducing, you may just create empty dummy files).

The `build.lua` should look like this:

```lua
-- varA/build.lua
#!/usr/bin/env texlua

module = "mymodulename"
pkgversion = "0.1-varA"
pkgdate = "26.06.2023"

-- create artefacts in the parent directory
maindir = ".."

-- look for source files in parent directory
sourcefiledir = "../src"
sourcefiles= {"**/*.dtx", "*.ins"}

-- look for documentation files in the common root
docfiledir = "../doc"
typesetfiles = {"*.tex"}

-- include partial tds trees
tdsdirs = { tex = "tex", fonts = "fonts", ../tex = "tex"}

-- keep the directory tree structure in build and tds
flatten = false
flattentds = false
```

- The crucial part is the syntax of the `tdsdirs` variable: the **keys** are the directories in my project, and the **values** are the tds tree locations the files are copied to (see [l3build documentation](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/l3build/l3build.pdf)).
- I have left out any `*.dtx` at this point, as it does not seem to be relevant.
- I have left out any documentation files, as they do not seem relevant.

However, the config is not working. If I remove the `../tex = tex` key-value pair, the config works, but then it searches for a directory `<project root>/varA/tex` to include instead of including `<project root>/tex`.

What I need is **a way to specify relative/parent paths as keys in tdsdirs**.
Is this possible, and how?

Comment: Yes, I want to pull from the parent directory. But the documentation (l3build) states:
"[...] the table tdsdirs is available. Each entry is a source directory and the
matching installation target, for example ``tdsdirs = {sources = "tex"}``.
This would enable a directory **sources** in the development area to be used for testing and typesetting, and for it to be installed into the **tex** tree when building a release."
So the syntax is quite unintuitive, and I think my interpretation is the correct one.
I have of course still tried your suggestion, but it does not map the root tex tree.

Comment: We don't currently support multiple configurations for release as ... that doesn't seem to make sense outside very particular circumstances. (The team do use a two-release strategy but based on the branch we are on for `develop` vs `main` for the LaTeX kernel.) Not directly part of the Q here, but I'm interested in the use case.

Comment: @JosephWright I have a professor who is adamant about "flat" directory structures, while I believe in separation of code and artefacts (and I want to teach that to students). So ultimately I have to maintain different variants of the templates for our institution, which only differ in their respective build configuration, hence I did not want to maintain multiple development branches. I understand its a niche use case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'll have a look into that and update the question with the additional information later.

Comment: What would happen if users install both variants? Wouldn't they end up with duplicated files?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, if users install both variants, they end up with duplicate files. Which files get preference is then up to their local texmf search tree configuration.

Comment: well I would avoid that. People never remember which option they used last time (I certainly wouldn't), and at every update you will get support requests why it doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I implemented the suggested solution by Joseph Wright and achieved a good result. So in fact, I need to use the keys in the way I wanted to set them up, but I didn't have the right syntax to do so.
However, I'm curious: Where else in the package source would you suggest to place pre-made *sty and *.cls files?

Comment: as you only have one or two I would list them individually in installfiles (I think)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Interesting. It never occured to me, that I could do it this way and I'll consider it from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remember that Lua only allows the 'shortcut' syntax

```lua
foo = { name = "value" }
```

when the `name` is alphanumeric. Here, you need to do things the 'complete' way:

```lua
tdsdirs["../tex"] = "tex"
```

as this will allow the use of `.` and `/` in the string.

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember what I never knew. However, this is exactly the information I have been lacking.

Comment: @marc I mean 'you' in the general sense - 'Users of `l3build` need to remember that the `build.lua` file is a Lua file and therefore must follow the general syntax of Lua', if we want to be formal :)